# Quick way to set all flags in database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am looking for a quick way to set all flags in a table so I tried this:

```
using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
{
    Parallel.ForEach(db.Companies.Where(x => x.CheckedCompaniesHouse == true).ToList(),async (c) =>
    {
        c.CheckedCompaniesHouse = false;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    });
}
```

But this doesn't work, its gives the error:

> "A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe."

I am pretty sure I have done something very similar to this before and it worked fine.  Can this approach work?

Is there a better way?

Comment: I sincerely doubt that `Parallel.ForEach` will improve your performance here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best way to do what you are trying to achieve is using [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended):

```
  db.Companies
    .Where(x => x.CheckedCompaniesHouse == true)
    .Update(t => new Company { CheckedCompaniesHouse = false });
```

Using this library you avoid the need to load the entities you want to modify into memory. The code I show above will be translated to a sql update batch.

Comment: I agree +1.This is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
db.YourTable.Where(x => x.TheId == TheParameterId && x.AnotherColumn == true).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    x.IsActive = false; x.UpdatedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
});
db.SaveChanges();
```

I don't know if there is an easy way to do it, without extensions and other libs.

But EF isn't very good with multiple updates like that, why don't you give it a try on Dapper?

Has async methods also.

And you could do it using plain and simple ADO.NET and SQL.

Something like:

```
connection.Execute("UPDATE Table SET Field = NewValue WHERE Column = @Parameter", new { Parameter = someParameterValue });
```

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: This will materialize the entire table into memory.  This is probably the most inefficient way to do this.

Comment: That's why I use Dapper for most common operations like that. Entity Framework will always lose against micro orms.


I asked a question just like this one and the answers were not so different from this.

Comment: @Morilon It is probably best to put the "load into memory" problem into your answer to make it more complete.